# Очистка экрана

Tags: g++, c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли функция для очистки экрана в С++? Использовать conio библиотеку не предлагать: ибо она не является стандартной и используется сугубо под винду, так же не тратьте время и не предлагайте циклы с кучей выводов нулевого символа. Нагуглил, что можно:

```
system("clear");
```

но g++ компилятор выдает:

> `static.cpp:29:19: error: ‘system’ was not declared in this scope`

То есть хотелось бы увидеть библиотеку и оператор очистки или библиотеку под систем("") для С++.

Comment: Вы в заблуждении! conio.h стандартная. И на собеседовании вас бы сразу за это отправили бы домой.

Comment: conio.h (от англ. console input-output — консольный ввод-вывод) — заголовочный файл, используемый в старых компиляторах, работающих в операционных системах MS-DOS, для создания текстового интерфейса пользователя.

Она стандартна лишь в компиляторах мелкомягкого. Так что поучите матчасть еще=)

Comment: Можно подумать, cls вам экран очистит. Это ведь тоже только под винду.

Comment: Это пример, под bash в линухе идет команда clear, в курсе я.

Comment: Она там идёт в случае, если она есть.

Comment: Стал бы я постить, если бы она шла, да еще и ошибку на нее указывающую копипастить.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Python - Clearing the terminal screen more elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34388390/4279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы работала system("clear"), подключайте stdlib.h Для винды system("cls");

Кроссплатформенный вариант:

`if (system("clear")) system( "cls" );`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! System("clear"); на маке сработал!

Answer (score 1):

1. conio.h действительно нет под nix.
2. Никто не мешает использовать библиотеку типа terminfo и/или (n)curses. Они вполне стандартные для *nix
3. cls под nix'ами также нет :) Чисто виндовая приблуда
4. А что мешает вместо system() сделать какой-нибудь exec для bash с нужными параметрами?
5. Или сделайте

   std::cout<<std::endl;

столько раз, сколько нужно (а сколько нужно? вот вопрос).

Comment: Спасибо)) Наконец кто-то по существу. А можно пример? Сейчас, конечно, сам попробую, но так, на всякий случай.

Answer (score 0):

clrscr();

попробуйте

Comment: "Таллекко ли то Таллинна? - Теперь уше таллеко." conio.h тут уже обсуждали. Вообще ТС хочет странного. Поскольку изначально терминал - печатающее устройство + клавиатура, то общего решения быть не может.